# memorystream to system.drawing.image with transparency

Tags: c#, itext

I have a pdf with an embedded image and using itextsharp I have read the image into a memorystream (after checking for subtype image).

```
byte[] bytes = TextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRStream)pdfStream);
```

after that I use

```
 using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
                                    {
                                        memStream.Position = 0;
                                        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream, true, true);
}
```

Further I save the image into a png using

```
img.Save(@"mypath to the file.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

#

The problem is most of the images are coming alright..however some of them are more like negatives..please see the image here.

http://pdfaid.com/prasad.bmp (similar result with png and gif)

Can someone please guide me how to solve this?

NOTE: instead of png I tried jpg and gif but didnot make a difference.

Thank you in advance,
Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

Read through the posts [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg54539.html) and hopefully they'll walk you through some answers. One person said that you might be [seeing a mask](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg54543.html) of some sort and another said you might be see an image with some [inverted color channels](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg54567.html). If you can post a specific PDF we might be able to help you more.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I still however cannot figure out how the image is in my pdf. I however found the following in the pdf..this is one of those images that is inverted. <</Intent/RelativeColorimetric/Subtype/Image/Length 563395/Filter/DCTDecode/Name/X/BitsPerComponent 8/ColorSpace/DeviceCMYK/Width 1280/Height 998/Type/XObject>>stream